# Can 'if' be used in conjunction with 'foreach' within 'template' binding Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using a knockout template to bind an observable array to the view. I have an array of objects, but I would like to only display objects that satisfy a certain condition.  Is there anyway to use the knockout template binding to do this?  I'm currently using the second solution presented (which works) because the first is resulting in an error, but I feel like there may be a more concise way to do it.

Desired solution (error that product is not defined):

```
<div class="productItem" data-bind="template: { name: 'product-template',foreach:'history', as:'product', if: product.Count === 1}"></div>
```

My workaround solution:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: history, as: 'product' } -->
<div class="productItem" data-bind="template: { name: 'product-template', if: product.Count === 1}"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: You should at least replace double-quotes for `"history"` with single. Also I'm sure you cannot combine `foreach` and `if` in one binding.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a clean way to do it in one statement, but perhaps you could move the `if` logic into the template itself?

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name:'template', foreach: items}">

</ul>
<script type="text/html" id="template">
  <!-- ko if: show -->
    <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

see the full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nheu9uvq/1/

Comment: The problem with this is that I want to be able to display different versions of the list (based on attributes of the elements).  This solution would require me to create multiple nearly identical templates for each different version of the list that I want to display (with different "if" bindings).

Comment: You could pass the field to be checked as a parameter to be checked in the template

Answer (score 0):

Use a `computed` to filter `history` based on its `Count` member. Or a function to filter based on an arbitrary member.

Answer (score 0):

The template binding itself supports an `if` parameter.

It's in the documentation. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html